# Is Mother's womb devoid of Maya (illusion)?

Tags: garuda-purana, maya

I was reading a book [Biography of Pothuluri Veerabrahmendra Swami](https://archive.org/details/VeerabrahmendraThePrecursorOfKalki1) and Author delineates the Vedic Science of development of Embryo in that book.

[Veerabrahmendra Swami or Brahmam garu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pothuluru_Veerabrahmendra) was a mystic saint who is believed to Avatar of Lord Vishnu and precursor of Kalki. Brahmam garu is famous for his work **Kaalagnaanam** (literally "Knowledge of time") which prophesy future events.

> “In that embryo, soul enters in the 7th month. That time onwards the
>   *pindam* remains upside down. It remains covered with a layer which protects it from the *jatharagni* (heat inside the mother’s stomach).
>   In the 8th and 9th months, Jeeva (Soul) has all knowledge of his
>   previous lives; and seeing the disgusting urine and faeces it feels
>   very sad to stay there and repents for his past bad karmas, pleads to
>   the God saying he would never do any bad deeds again and would at
>   least in this life be very wise and pious person devoted to Dharma and
>   god. This way he promises to God in various tones of sadness and
>   requests god to free him from that hellish place which seems so
>   disgusting to him.
>
> *But as soon as he comes out of the womb to the actual world, due to
>   Maya/Illusion as soon as he cries for the first time, he forgets all
>   his previous knowledge and becomes totally ignorant!”*

[Garuda Puranam](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu08.htm) too describes similar events.

> 13. There he remembers, by divine power, the Karma generated in hundreds of previous births,--and remembering, sobs for a long time,
>       obtaining not the least happiness.
> 14. Having this insight he, with hands put together, bound in seven bonds, imploring and trembling, adores in plaintive tones Him who
>       placed him in the womb.
> 15. From the beginning of the seventh month, though he gains consciousness, he who is in the womb trembles and moves about because
>       of the parturition winds, like a uterine worm.
>
> 16-23. The creature says, "I seek refuge in Viṣṇu; the husband of Śrī,
>   the supporter of the universe, the destroyer of evil, who is
>   compassionate to those who come for shelter.
>
> "I am bewildered by Thy magic, as regards body and son and wife;
>   misled by my egoism I am transmigrating, O Lord.
>
> "I did good and evil actions for the sake of my dependents, and as s
>   result I am tormented, while they who enjoy the fruits escape.
>
> "If I am released from this womb I will lay myself at Thy feet, and I
>   will take the means by which I may obtain liberation.
>
> "Fallen into a well of fœces and urine, I am burnt by the fire of the
>   belly, and anxious to escape from it. When shall I get out?
>
> "In Him alone, who has given me this experience, and is compassionate
>   to the afflicted, will I seek refuge. Let not this transmigration
>   occur to me again.
>
> "But no, I wish never to come out of the womb, where misery results
>   from my sinful actions.
>
> "Because remaining even here in great misery, bearing the fatigue,
>   resorting to Thy feet I will keep myself aloof from the worlds of
>   change."
>
> 24. The Blessed Lord said: He who has thus considered, and has been ten months in the womb, endowed with insight, while praying, suddenly
>       is cast out head downwards into birth, by the winds of delivery.
> 25. Cast out forcibly, bending down his head, he comes out with anxiety and painfully breathless and with memory destroyed.
> 26. Having fallen on the ground he moves like a worm in excrement. He is become changed in condition, and cries loudly, deprived of
>       knowledge.
> 27. If the state of mind which arises in the womb, during illness, on the cremation ground, or upon hearing the Purāṇas were permanent--who
>       would not be liberated from bondage!
> 28. *When he comes out of the womb, after experiencing his karma, then verily the man is bewildered by the magic of Viṣṇu.*

Both these texts say man is bewildered by Maya when he comes out of the womb. Does this mean that mother's womb is free from Maya?

Comment: There's the famous story of Vyasa's son Shuka who refused to leave the womb because he did not want to lose his Jnana by being born, so then Krishna comes and gives the unborn baby a boon that he will retain his Jnana after being born.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan does this mean mother's womb is devoid of Maya?

Comment: Well, I'm not an Advaitin, so I don't subscribe to the world being an illusion.  But in any case, yeah, I think there's quite a bit of support that when you're in the womb you're devoid of Avidya, or at least you have less Avidya compared to after birth.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What about Magic of Lord Vishnu as Garuda Puranam says?

Comment: Not devoid of maya but definitely less avidya as @KeshavSrinivasan said.I think this avidya grows with the gradual development of our senses.So this imply a child has less avidya than adults!